# Swift Codable not able to decode if string contains (") in one of the values

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

This is a sample string which I am trying to decode via JSONDecoder to a corresponding object.

```
let errorString = """
{
    "ErrorCode":"5500",
    "ErrorMessage":"Not \"At all\" supported"
}
"""
```

Object :

```
struct FErrorResponse: Decodable {
    let errorCode: String
    let errorMessage: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case errorCode = "ErrorCode"
        case errorMessage = "ErrorMessage"
    }
}
```

Decoding Code :

```
let json = errorString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
let decoder = JSONDecoder()

do {
    let errorRes = try decoder.decode(FErrorResponse.self, from: json)
    print("Code : \(String(describing: errorRes.errorCode)), Message : \(String(describing: errorRes.errorMessage))")
    if errorRes.errorCode == "5500" {
        print("Super error")
    }
} catch let error {
    print("Error >> \(error)")
}
```

Error Displayed :

```
Error >> dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Badly formed object around character 43." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Badly formed object around character 43.})))
```

If my input string is following, it works without any issues,

```
let errorString = """
{
"ErrorCode":"5500",
"ErrorMessage":"Not supported"
}
"""
```

**NOTE:**
Online Json formatter tools correctly parses the input string. If I even use ObjectMapper's tool, it correct parses. Only if I am doing the decoding using Codable, it gives the above error mentioned.

-> This is just a sample code written to highlight the actual issue. The string data received from server contains similar values, (Strings which contains " around it are properly escaped) inside the response.

Please help.

Comment: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5552 Works if you do `"ErrorMessage":"Not \\"At all\\" supported"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape \

```
let str = """
    {
       "ErrorCode":"5500",
        "ErrorMessage":"Not \\"At all\\" supported"
    }
"""
```